# retrieving user data from api (x-api-key)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I'm beginner javascript programmer, here trying to retrieve user information using fetch, question is, is there any easy way to search for a specific person for example : Laurel Gates USERID: 987654321
English is not my mother language so sory for mistakes.
here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Retrieve</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
       fetch("https://*******.****-.com/",{
        method:"GET",
        headers:{
                 "Content-type": "application/json",
                 "X-API-Key": "o************************G" 
    }
})
    .then( function(vastaus) {
        if(vastaus.ok){
            return vastaus.json();
        }
    })
    .then( function(tiedot) {
        console.log(tiedot);
    })
    .catch( function(virhe) {
        console.log('ERROR: ', virhe.message);
    }); 
    </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you attach JSON example to give you the best solution?

Comment: @NBlack is it possible in email  to discuss this and then you can answer the question here ?

Comment: Sorry, always is best to talk here, everybody can learn from our errors, that made stackoverflow. I think that you can resolve your problem using find method. Check this: https://appdividend.com/2018/12/17/javascript-array-find-example-array-prototype-find-tutorial/ (the only difference is that you have objects instead numbers in array)

Comment: @NBlack one more question related to this same thing, i have two end points for 'details' and 'otheraccounts'. Both endpoints use the same 'X-API-Key' same value. But for some reason 'details' is working but for 'otheraccounts' i get error : Access to fetch at 'https://qmk/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.also this: GET https://qmk net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous)ERROR:Failed to fetch

Comment: If two endpoints have same server address and you receive CORS error probably your backend is not understanding what are you sending and give error 500 (other option is that your second endpoint not exist or is not well implemented). Try to read logs in your backend. Second option if you try to use two different servers and use cross-origin google chrome block it sometimes (use chrome-gadget "Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to test your script but maybe its better to call other places from backend and send to frontend)

Comment: @NBlack same url https://qmk*****.****-.com/user/otheraccounts/details  this one works without any problem but this one https://qmk*****.****-.com/user/otheraccounts is not working, and these both use same endpoints also, both should works with the same code.i don't have access to backend but they told me both uses same endpoints (same key/values) and it should workd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210457/discussion-between-nblack-and-walee).

Comment: @NBlack i used that chrome-gadget and now im getting one error : GET https://qmk*****.****-.com/user/otheraccounts/ 404

Comment: Stackoverflow chat fall

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After talk through chat problem comes from Content-Response and response without some property called by console.log